# An antenna directed towards a satellite emits signals of thousands of W/m². If a bird flies in front of that antenna, isn't there a risk of death?

Tags: power, rf

Signals from antennas directed to satellites can reach hundreds of MW/m<sup>2</sup> in EIRP.

Would such high-power signals not cause damage to a bird or even a person blocking that signal, even for a few seconds?
After all, there are limits on exposure to these electromagnetic signals, aren't there?

Comment: `hundreds of MW/m2` at what distance? ... why would they need to output that much power?

Comment: For the distance of almost 36,000 km.

Comment: When I was in the Navy, I watched one of our radars blow up a seagull.

Comment: I'm not sure you've got your numbers right. Perhaps 100's of KW rather than 100's of MW? Aren't ordinary comm satellite base stations less than 10KW EIRP? Near field on high power antennas is dangerous, and does kill birds. It's one of the reasons for shielding. (That's not EIRP)

Comment: Where do your numbers come from? Even deeps space antennas have powers around 20kW and are 100's square metres, so power flux density is in the 100's w/M2. Also, EIRP is a measure of power (w), not power flux density (w/m2)

Comment: Also, EIRP doesn't tell you how much power it is actually transmitting - it is the transmitted power multiplied by the antenna gain. For parabolic antenna's used for satellite communication, the gain can be 1,000 - 10,000 or more, so the EIRP is several orders of magnitude higher than the actual power.

Comment: @JrBennitoBennito no, the question was not "what distance does the uplink need to bridge", but "at what distance from the transmit antenna is that the area power density"? Because that's not a sensible unit for describing an antenna! Think about how area illuminated by a beam grows with the *square* of distance, and you'll see that you need to say "how far was I from the antenna when I meausured that it's \$x\$ W/m²", and not only "it's \$x\$ W/m²".

Comment: As I said, as close as possible to the transmitting antenna. Can consider 1 to 100 meters away.

Answer (score 2):

In principle yes, it could be harmful, but:

- one must be close to the sending antenna, because the "beam" disperses quickly.
- It depends on the wavelength. Molecular resonances are good at absorbing radio waves. Transmission is chosen to be *not* blocked by things such as water or air. Because your body is much water, that leaves only few things to absorb efficiently.

Comment: Usually the lobe of a satellite dish is narrow, because they want a target, without much dispersion...
Although the transmitter power is on the order of less than 1kW, its EIRP equivalent can easily reach tens of MW.

When I represent the risk of danger, I am considering a reasonable approach to the transmitting antenna.

For example, an antenna with 100 MW (EIRP), in the vicinity may have 10kW/m².

A radar, on the other hand, such power can easily reach tens of MW.

I am very grateful to you for your answers.